# Why a union all queries are repeating the data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure which returns these columns for different ledger types but for each type it repeats the data, I tried figuring out but couldn't.

I went through each line and every union but still it repeats the data for each type. There were few other issues i have removed along the lines but this one is giving me headache.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_Rpt_TrailBalance] --2,8
    @Company int = null,
    @YTD    date = null
As
Begin

    declare @FromDate date
    declare @ToDate date
    declare @CurrentYear int
    declare @PreviousMonth int
    declare @CurrentMonth int
    declare @PreviousYear int
    declare @Period int

    set @CurrentYear = year(@YTD) 

set @FromDate =    CAST('01/01/' + CAST( @CurrentYear as varchar(4)) as Date)
set @ToDate = @YTD  

--If @Period = 1
--Begin
--  set @StartingMonth = 1
--End

--Else

--Begin
--set @StartingMonth = month(getdate())
--End

    --set @ToDate = month(getdate())
    set @PreviousMonth = month(getdate()) - 1
    --set @CurrentYear = year(getdate())
    set @PreviousYear = year(getdate()) - 1

    Select
    comp.CompanyCode, g.Currency, g.GLAccountNo, c.GLAccountLongText as 'ShortText', g.BusinessArea,
    (
    --(select isnull(sum(g1.Amount),0) from GLedger g1 where g1.DC = 'Debit' and month(vi.PostingDate) = 12 and year(vi.PostingDate) = @PreviousYear and g1.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g1.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g2.Amount),0) from GLedger g2 where g2.DC = 'Credit' and month(vi.PostingDate) = 12 and year(vi.PostingDate) = @PreviousYear and g2.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g2.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    ) as 'C/fwd balance',
    (
    case when @Period = 1 then
    --(select isnull(sum(g3.Amount),0) from GLedger g3 where g3.DC = 'Debit' and month(vi.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @PreviousMonth and year(vi.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g3.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g3.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g4.Amount),0) from GLedger g4 where g4.DC = 'Credit' and month(vi.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @PreviousMonth and year(vi.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g4.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g4.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    else
    --(select isnull(sum(g3.Amount),0) from GLedger g3 where g3.DC = 'Debit' and month(vi.PostingDate) = @PreviousMonth and year(vi.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g3.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g3.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g4.Amount),0) from GLedger g4 where g4.DC = 'Credit' and month(vi.PostingDate) = @PreviousMonth and year(vi.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g4.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g4.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    end
    ) as 'Previous Month',
    isnull((select sum(dr.Amount) from GLedger dr where dr.DC = 'Debit' and dr.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and dr.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea and vi.PostingDate between @FromDate and @ToDate),0) as 'Reporting Debit',
    isnull((select abs(sum(cr.Amount)) from GLedger cr where cr.DC = 'Credit' and cr.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and cr.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea and vi.PostingDate between @FromDate and @ToDate),0) as 'Reporting Credit'
    from GLedger g --, COA c, Company p
    Inner Join Company comp
    ON comp.CompanyID= g.CompanyID
    Inner join COA c
    ON c.GLAccount= g.GLAccountNo
    Inner Join VendorInvoice vi 
    ON vi.VendorInvoice_ID= g.MainID and g.LedgerType_ID= 1
    where 
    g.GLAccountNo = c.GLAccount and
    comp.CompanyID = @Company and                   --VendorInvoices
    --month(vi.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @ToDate
    --and year(vi.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear
    (vi.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @ToDate
    and isnull(g.Active,0) = 1
    group by comp.CompanyCode, g.Currency, g.GLAccountNo, c.GLAccountLongText, g.BusinessArea, vi.PostingDate
    --order by g.GLAccountNo

    UNION ALL 


    Select
    comp.CompanyCode, g.Currency, g.GLAccountNo, c.GLAccountLongText as 'ShortText', g.BusinessArea,
    (
    --(select isnull(sum(g1.Amount),0) from GLedger g1 where g1.DC = 'Debit' and month(vi.PostingDate) = 12 and year(vi.PostingDate) = @PreviousYear and g1.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g1.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g2.Amount),0) from GLedger g2 where g2.DC = 'Credit' and month(vi.PostingDate) = 12 and year(vi.PostingDate) = @PreviousYear and g2.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g2.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    ) as 'C/fwd balance',
    (
    case when @Period = 1 then
    --(select isnull(sum(g3.Amount),0) from GLedger g3 where g3.DC = 'Debit' and month(vi.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @PreviousMonth and year(vi.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g3.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g3.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g4.Amount),0) from GLedger g4 where g4.DC = 'Credit' and month(vi.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @PreviousMonth and year(vi.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g4.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g4.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    else
    --(select isnull(sum(g3.Amount),0) from GLedger g3 where g3.DC = 'Debit' and month(vi.PostingDate) = @PreviousMonth and year(vi.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g3.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g3.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g4.Amount),0) from GLedger g4 where g4.DC = 'Credit' and month(vi.PostingDate) = @PreviousMonth and year(vi.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g4.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g4.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    end
    ) as 'Previous Month',
    isnull((select sum(dr.Amount) from GLedger dr where dr.DC = 'Debit' and dr.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and dr.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea and  vi.PostingDate between @FromDate and @ToDate),0) as 'Reporting Debit',
    isnull((select abs(sum(cr.Amount)) from GLedger cr where cr.DC = 'Credit' and cr.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and cr.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea and vi.PostingDate between @FromDate and @ToDate),0) as 'Reporting Credit'
    from GLedger g --, COA c, Company p
    Inner Join Company comp
    ON comp.CompanyID= g.CompanyID
    Inner join COA c
    ON c.GLAccount= g.GLAccountNo
    Inner Join VendorInvoice VI
    ON VI.VendorInvoice_ID= g.MainID
    Inner Join VendorInvoiceTransactions VIT
    ON G.SubID = VIT.VendorTransactionsID and G.LedgerType_ID = 2   --VendorInvoiceTransactions
    where 
    g.GLAccountNo = c.GLAccount and
    comp.CompanyID = @Company and                   
    --month(vi.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @ToDate
    --and year(vi.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear
    (vi.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @ToDate
    and isnull(g.Active,0) = 1
    group by comp.CompanyCode, g.Currency, g.GLAccountNo, c.GLAccountLongText, g.BusinessArea, vi.PostingDate

    UNION ALL 

    Select
    comp.CompanyCode, g.Currency, g.GLAccountNo, c.GLAccountLongText as 'ShortText', g.BusinessArea,
    (
    --(select isnull(sum(g1.Amount),0) from GLedger g1 where g1.DC = 'Debit' and month(s.BillingDate) = 12 and year(s.BillingDate) = @PreviousYear and g1.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g1.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g2.Amount),0) from GLedger g2 where g2.DC = 'Credit' and month(s.BillingDate) = 12 and year(s.BillingDate) = @PreviousYear and g2.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g2.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    ) as 'C/fwd balance',
    (
    case when @Period = 1 then
    --(select isnull(sum(g3.Amount),0) from GLedger g3 where g3.DC = 'Debit' and month(s.BillingDate) between @FromDate and @PreviousMonth and year(s.BillingDate) = @CurrentYear and g3.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g3.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g4.Amount),0) from GLedger g4 where g4.DC = 'Credit' and month(s.BillingDate) between @FromDate and @PreviousMonth and year(s.BillingDate) = @CurrentYear and g4.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g4.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) 
    0
    else
    --(select isnull(sum(g3.Amount),0) from GLedger g3 where g3.DC = 'Debit' and month(s.BillingDate) = @PreviousMonth and year(s.BillingDate) = @CurrentYear and g3.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g3.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g4.Amount),0) from GLedger g4 where g4.DC = 'Credit' and month(s.BillingDate) = @PreviousMonth and year(s.BillingDate) = @CurrentYear and g4.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g4.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    end
    ) as 'Previous Month',
    isnull((select sum(dr.Amount) from GLedger dr where dr.DC = 'Debit' and dr.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and dr.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea and s.BillingDate between @FromDate and @ToDate),0) as 'Reporting Debit',
    isnull((select abs(sum(cr.Amount)) from GLedger cr where cr.DC = 'Credit' and cr.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and cr.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea and s.BillingDate between @FromDate and @ToDate),0) as 'Reporting Credit'
    from GLedger g --, COA c, Company p
    Inner Join Company comp
    ON comp.CompanyID= g.CompanyID
    Inner join COA c
    ON c.GLAccount= g.GLAccountNo
    Inner Join Sales S 
    ON G.MainID = S.SalesID and G.LedgerType_ID = 3   --Sales
    where 
    g.GLAccountNo = c.GLAccount and
    comp.CompanyID = @Company and                   
    --month(s.BillingDate) between @FromDate and @ToDate
    --and year(s.BillingDate) = @CurrentYear
    (s.BillingDate) between @FromDate and @ToDate
    and isnull(g.Active,0) = 1
    group by comp.CompanyCode, g.Currency, g.GLAccountNo, c.GLAccountLongText, g.BusinessArea, s.BillingDate

    UNION ALL 

    Select
    comp.CompanyCode, g.Currency, g.GLAccountNo, c.GLAccountLongText as 'ShortText', g.BusinessArea,
    (
    --(select isnull(sum(g1.Amount),0) from GLedger g1 where g1.DC = 'Debit' and month(ST.PricingDate) = 12 and year(g1.Datetime) = @PreviousYear and g1.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g1.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g2.Amount),0) from GLedger g2 where g2.DC = 'Credit' and month(ST.PricingDate) = 12 and year(g2.Datetime) = @PreviousYear and g2.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g2.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    ) as 'C/fwd balance',
    (
    case when @Period = 1 then
    --(select isnull(sum(g3.Amount),0) from GLedger g3 where g3.DC = 'Debit' and month(ST.PricingDate) between @FromDate and @PreviousMonth and year(ST.PricingDate) = @CurrentYear and g3.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g3.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g4.Amount),0) from GLedger g4 where g4.DC = 'Credit' and month(ST.PricingDate) between @FromDate and @PreviousMonth and year(ST.PricingDate) = @CurrentYear and g4.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g4.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    else
    --(select isnull(sum(g3.Amount),0) from GLedger g3 where g3.DC = 'Debit' and month(ST.PricingDate) = @PreviousMonth and year(ST.PricingDate) = @CurrentYear and g3.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g3.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g4.Amount),0) from GLedger g4 where g4.DC = 'Credit' and month(ST.PricingDate) = @PreviousMonth and year(ST.PricingDate) = @CurrentYear and g4.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g4.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    end
    ) as 'Previous Month',
    isnull((select sum(dr.Amount) from GLedger dr where dr.DC = 'Debit' and dr.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and dr.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea and ST.PricingDate between @FromDate and @ToDate),0) as 'Reporting Debit',
    isnull((select abs(sum(cr.Amount)) from GLedger cr where cr.DC = 'Credit' and cr.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and cr.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea and ST.PricingDate between @FromDate and @ToDate),0) as 'Reporting Credit'
    from GLedger g --, COA c, Company p
    Inner Join Company comp
    ON comp.CompanyID= g.CompanyID
    Inner join COA c
    ON c.GLAccount= g.GLAccountNo
    Inner Join SalesTransactions ST 
    ON G.SubID = ST.SalesTransactionID and G.LedgerType_ID = 4  --SalesTransactions
    where 
    g.GLAccountNo = c.GLAccount and
    comp.CompanyID = @Company and                   
    --month(ST.PricingDate) between @FromDate and @ToDate
    --and year(ST.PricingDate) = @CurrentYear
    (ST.PricingDate) between @FromDate and @ToDate
    and isnull(g.Active,0) = 1
    group by comp.CompanyCode, g.Currency, g.GLAccountNo, c.GLAccountLongText, g.BusinessArea, ST.PricingDate

    UNION ALL 

    Select
    comp.CompanyCode, g.Currency, g.GLAccountNo, c.GLAccountLongText as 'ShortText', g.BusinessArea,
    (
    --(select isnull(sum(g1.Amount),0) from GLedger g1 where g1.DC = 'Debit' and month(AP.PostingDate) = 12 and year(AP.PostingDate) = @PreviousYear and g1.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g1.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g2.Amount),0) from GLedger g2 where g2.DC = 'Credit' and month(AP.PostingDate) = 12 and year(AP.PostingDate) = @PreviousYear and g2.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g2.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    ) as 'C/fwd balance',
    (
    case when @Period = 1 then
    --(select isnull(sum(g3.Amount),0) from GLedger g3 where g3.DC = 'Debit' and month(AP.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @PreviousMonth and year(AP.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g3.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g3.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g4.Amount),0) from GLedger g4 where g4.DC = 'Credit' and month(AP.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @PreviousMonth and year(AP.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g4.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g4.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    else
    --(select isnull(sum(g3.Amount),0) from GLedger g3 where g3.DC = 'Debit' and month(AP.PostingDate) = @PreviousMonth and year(AP.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g3.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g3.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea) +
    --(select isnull(sum(g4.Amount),0) from GLedger g4 where g4.DC = 'Credit' and month(AP.PostingDate) = @PreviousMonth and year(AP.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear and g4.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and g4.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea)
    0
    end
    ) as 'Previous Month',
    isnull((select sum(dr.Amount) from GLedger dr where dr.DC = 'Debit' and dr.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and dr.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea and AP.PostingDate between @FromDate and @ToDate ),0) as 'Reporting Debit',
    isnull((select abs(sum(cr.Amount)) from GLedger cr where cr.DC = 'Credit' and cr.GLAccountNo = g.GLAccountNo and cr.BusinessArea = g.BusinessArea and AP.PostingDate between @FromDate and @ToDate),0) as 'Reporting Credit'
    from GLedger g --, COA c, Company p
    Inner Join Company comp
    ON comp.CompanyID= g.CompanyID
    Inner join COA c
    ON c.GLAccount= g.GLAccountNo
    Inner Join  tblAccountsInvoicePayable AP 
    ON G.MainID = AP.PayableInvoice_ID and G.LedgerType_ID = 5  --AccountsInvoicePayable
    where 
    g.GLAccountNo = c.GLAccount and
    comp.CompanyID = @Company and                   
    --month(AP.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @ToDate
    --and year(AP.PostingDate) = @CurrentYear
    (AP.PostingDate) between @FromDate and @ToDate
    and isnull(g.Active,0) = 1
    group by comp.CompanyCode, g.Currency, g.GLAccountNo, c.GLAccountLongText, g.BusinessArea, AP.PostingDate
end
```

Answer (score 3):

So keep in mind that **UNION** command combines the results of two or more *SELECT* statements but only keeps the distinct values.

````
E.g.
table1 --> 1,2,3,4,5
table2 --> 1,2,4,5,6,7

```
SELECT c FROM table1
UNION
SELECT c FROM table2; 
```

Result --> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
````

On the other hand, the **UNION ALL** command merges the results of two or more *SELECT* statements and allows duplicates.

````
E.g.
table1 --> 1,2,3,4,5
table2 --> 1,2,4,5,6,7

```
SELECT c FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT c FROM table2; 
```

Result --> 1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,7
````

[READ HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union.asp)

[EXAMPLES HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`. A simple search over the net will tell the following difference:

`UNION ALL` keeps all of the records from each of the original data sets, `UNION` removes any duplicate records.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want duplicate results, use UNION rather than UNION ALL.

UNION ALL keeps all of the records from each of the original datasets, UNION eliminates duplicate rows.